# Speed of various template engines paired with the Falcon Python Cloud API?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm thinking about building a small web application using the Falcon Cloud API framework.  I'd like to ask the community for some ideas on the matter of templating.

What's the speed of Falcon (https://github.com/racker/falcon) with Jinja2?
...with Mako?
...with Tenjin?

Comment: I just want to point out that the `falcon` tag is for the [Falcon programming language](http://www.falconpl.org) and not the Falcon framework you are referring to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use anything you like. Jinja2 has great support, so I would recommend that you use it. However, if you are looking for really high speeds, then go for mako.

Comment: Tenjin looks pretty spicy too.  Thank you! http://www.kuwata-lab.com/tenjin/pytenjin-users-guide.html